# Finding posts tagged with ALL tags

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I have a `Post` and `Tag` model that are joined through a `Tagging` model with `has_many :through`

I am passing in `params[:tag_ids]` from my form and I'm trying to get all posts that are tagged with **all the tags** (not just with any one of the tags).

I'm trying the following:

```
@ftags = params[:tags_ids]

@objArray = Array.new

@ftags.each do |tag| 
  @array = Tagging.where("tag_id=#{tag}")
  @objArray.push @array
end
```

...and now what I want to do is to combine these queries somehow to get the right posts. Before when I only had two queries I used to combine with the merge command like this:

```
@result = @query1.merge(@query2)
```

...but now I have a dynamic number of queries and I still want to combine them in the end. How do I do something like the merge inside of a loop on a specific value for a specific column?

Comment: Why can't you do one query? `Post.where('x = ? OR y = ? OR z = ?', x, y, x)'`

Comment: I get the number of the things I wanna look for "query on" from the user. its stored in an array of ID's. so its dynamic and I have to loop on the array to get each query result.

Comment: Can you post that part of the code please.

Comment: Can you put the actual queries too please.  With the conditionals.

Comment: the query is in inside the loop "@array = Tagging.where("tag_id=#{tag}")"

Comment: it is then pushed inside the objarray

Comment: or @array = Tagging.where('tag_id is in (?)', params[:tags_ids])

Comment: @dennis I already tried that and it ends up giving me every post that has a tag_id inside the [tags_ids]. what I wanna do is get the post that only has all the [tags_ids] in the tag_id inside the model taggings

Comment: Show the parts of your Post and Tagging models that show how a post and a tag are associated.

Comment: Ok, there you go, new answer posted.

Comment: I've fixed your question too, take note of the end result - which is how this sort of thing should be asked.

Answer (score 5):

You have a list of tag IDs and want to find all posts that have all these tags:

```
# contains [1, 2, 3]
tag_ids = params[:tag_ids]

Post.joins(:taggings)
    .where(taggings: { tag: tag_ids })
    .group('posts.id')
    .having("count(taggings.id) = #{tag_ids.length}")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pull back separate sets of `post_id`s and then take an intersection of the lists to get the posts that are in all the lists (ie. the posts that have all the tags).

```
post_ids = []
params[:tags_ids].each do |tag_id|
  post_ids << Tagging.select(:post_id).where(tag_id: tag_id)
end

Post.where id: post_ids.reduce &:&
```

...but @janfoeh's answer is better.

*[edited to correct erroneous comment about not being able to do this in a single SQL query]*

Comment: Sorry, but that's not correct; you can do that with plain SQL.

Comment: I don't do this light heartedly, believe me. Without the intro, it would just be an alternative solution, and I would not have downvoted it. Why not remove it? ;) And thank you for being a good sportsman about it!